# Can you please verify what I think to have found as a periodicity of the Kolakoski sequence with period 1560?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you please verify what I think to have found as a periodicity of the Kolakoski sequence with period 1560?

The graphic below displays the sequence in rows of 30 each.
The periodicity seems to set in at the beginning of row 8 (perhaps earlier?) which would be sequence position 151 and repeats every 52nd row (every 1560th entry)

[image]

Comment: thanks Christian ... I misspelled it ... just corrected ... Kolakoski

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I think they mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence

Comment: thanks Donald ... in my preliminary post, I had misspelled it

Comment: so below appears a color map of
$$ K_{i}−K_{i+1560}$$

[![deviations from 1560 periodicity][1]][1]  [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/acEQG.jpg

Comment: As far as I remember, the reason why proving that the density of $1$'s exists is the fact that the frequency seems to get close to 1/2 but oscilates a lot. I remember I saw few years ago a graph of the frequencies of 1's up to a really large number, and the frequency was getting closer to 1/2 but oscillate a lot. This is not possible if the sequence is becoming periodic at an early stage.

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce your result. Below is a screen shot of the first $10000$ values in the sequence and then a list of where $K_i$ differs from $K_{i+1560}$.

Code & clearer images available upon request.

[image]

Comment: yes, the 1560 periodicity is broken individually at i = 1347, 2127, 4258, 5038, 7169, 7949, 9300, 10080 etc ....

Comment: I am a c# coder ... I start my indexing at zero ... a[0]=1;a[1]=2;a[2]=2;a[3]=1;a[4]=1 ... do I need to subtract one from the above values ?

Comment: the near-periodicity doesn't start at i = 1 though .... it starts at around i = 151 such that for i>151 $$ K_{i} = K_{i+1560} $$ with regular exceptions.  My guess is that larger near-periodicity gaps can be found ... for a given gap, my guess would be that the sequence of deviation from periodicity would replay the sequence itself

Comment: $P_{1347}$ & $P_{1347+1560}$ agree. $P_{2127}$ & $P_{2127+1560}$ disagree. the next two agree & disagree .... I have just put in a count & they diagree $4393$ times in the first $10000$.

Comment: hmmm ... I'm only counting 21 total disagreements in the first 10000 with 14 of those occurring when i<=52

Comment: darn ... found a mistake in my code ... ugh

Comment: Tis human to err ... Show me the man who never made a mistake & I will show you the man who never made anything ... Really don't worry ... we all make mistakes ... & we learn from them ... delete your question (if you want to) ... & thanks for letting me know $\ddot \smile$